# How install ubuntu-desktop from the source?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I do not have an access to the internet from my device with Ubuntu 18.04 software and my question is how could I install a desktop?
`sudo apt-get ubuntu-desktop` doesn't work so I thought that it is possible to install it from the source, but I can't find it.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ is probably better suited for this question.

Answer (score 0):

First, install the **taskel manager**

```
sudo apt-get install taskel
```

Then, you can choose a Dislpay manager, I suggest **lightdm**

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

Then, choose your desktop enviroment.

For GNOME: run `taskel`.

For KDE Plasma: run `sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop`

You have a variety of Desktop Enviroments you can find [here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-a-gui-on-ubuntu)